# Blazor wasm not loading index.html when starting server project

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a blazor wasm app and when I boot the project from the server, the client page that opens doesn't load index.html, it doesn't even make a request to get it.

At first it worked correctly, but as the project grew it stopped working. I have been working on the server and at the moment I have not made any changes on the client.

Starting only the client project, it loads correctly, from what I understand that I must have touched something on the server that affects startup.

The program.cs in the server is found as follows

```
using ShareParking.Auth.UI.Api.Middleware;
using ShareParking.Core.Server.TraceLogger;
using ShareParking.DI;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WatchDog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

Configurator.ConfigureCore(builder.Services, builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

Trace.Listeners.Add(new MongoLogListener(app.Services, builder.Configuration));
Trace.TraceInformation("INFO>>");
Trace.TraceWarning("WARNING>>");
Trace.TraceError("ERROR>>");

app.UseWatchDogExceptionLogger();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.UseWatchDog(con =>
{
    con.WatchPageUsername = "admin";
    con.WatchPagePassword = "admin";
});

app.ApplyTokenValidation(builder.Configuration.GetSection("SecretKey").Value);

app.Run();
```

I have checked the typical, that the index does not move, that the references are not corrupted. Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Thanks in advance

Anyone who has gone through the same thing and can guide me to find a solution

Comment: In case it can be useful for someone. In my case, the WatchDog interfered and did not allow the view to be loaded correctly. I have disabled it, pending to find another option, or solution